# java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/final-servlet.xml]

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, maven, spring-mvc

I am creating simple maven project plugin . 
Application directory structure is like standard maven project directory structure.

I have place application-context.xml file  under src/main/java/resources folder.

**Problem :**

How to configure this path in web.xml file ?

I am getting java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource `[/WEB-INF/final-servlet.xml]` error

Do i have to configure my project properties in eclipse???

Can any one guide me on the same....??

Thanks in advance..>!

Comment: Did you mean /src/main/resources? In any case, we don't know how you're trying to access the file, so diagnosing what's gone wrong is difficult.

Comment: how to access ..?? i dont know . I just created folder structure and welcome file. I am just tasting my framework.

Comment: when i build and run it using eclipse it gives java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/final-servlet.xml] error On console

Comment: We don't know what you're doing. If you're just creating a spring web project put the file in the right location.

Comment: I am creating plugin project for future reference

Answer (score 3):

Put the final-servlet.xml under WEB-INF folder and it will works. What you are asking about your application-context.xml i think is something like this:

```xml
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        WEB-INF/final-servlet.xml
        classpath:application-context.xml
    </param>
</context-param>
```

Comment: How can we access these files for `BufferedWriter` in the Service layer?

Answer (score 1):

Files in the resources directory are deployed to the classpath, not `WEB-INF`. If you want the file in `WEB-INF` then it needs to be in `src/webapp/WEB-INF`, as in any Maven-based web app project.

Otherwise the location referenced in the Spring config needs to be classpath-relative.

Answer (score 0):

/WEB-INF/final-servlet.xml - in context-param in DispatcherServlet

and put final-servlet.xml in your_web_app/WEB-INF folder.

Should work